# Syntax error in my if else statement

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I keep getting a syntax error for the very last else in this set of code and I have no idea why. Its not an error with spacing its just syntax so I Don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I was wondering if someone could help. The code is below.

```
if pcolor == winner:
        print ('Correct!')

        while player == correct:
            phl = input('Higher or lower?').strip().lower()
            randcard = computer_pick_card()
            if randcard == 'A':
                player = correct
                print ('The card was an Ace')
                print ('Correct!')

            else:   
                if last_card != ():
                    if phl == higher:
                        if randcard >= last_card:
                            player = correct
                            print ('The card was ', randcard)
                            print ('Correct!')

                        elif randcard < last_card:
                            player != correct
                            print ('The card was ', randcard)
                            print ('You lose')
                    elif phl == lower:
                        if randcard >= last_card:
                            player != correct
                            print ('The card was ', randcard)
                            print ('You lose')

                        elif randcard < last_card:
                            player == correct
                            print ('The card was ', randcard)
                            print ('Correct!')

                else:
                    if phl == higher:
                        if randcard >= card2:
                            player = correct
                            print ('The card was ', randcard)
                            print ('Correct!')

                        elif randcard < card2:
                            player != correct
                            print ('The card was ', randcard)
                            print ('You lose')
                    elif phl == lower:
                        if randcard > card2:
                            player != correct
                            print ('The card was ', randcard)
                            print ('You lose')

                        elif randcard <= card2:
                            player == correct
                            print ('The card was ', randcard)
                            print ('Correct!')

            last_card = randcard
            return last_card

    last_card = ()
    else:
        print ('You lose')
```

Comment: What is the error, exactly?

Comment: .you are completely mixing definition of variables with if statements...you should read the basics in python "player = correct" is a definition but not player == definition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python spacing is syntax.

You don't have the spacing right.

```
if ...
    ...
    last_card = ()
    else:
        ...
```

Should be

```
if ...
    ...
    last_card = ()
else:
    ...
```